# Alternatives to WMI

Tags: wmi

For Windows, what other frameworks or programming languages I could use that are similar to WMI's monitoring and system management functionalities?

Comment: [Powershell!!](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx)

Comment: I thought powershell uses WMI? or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most comparable to WMI's performance monitoring features is [SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379100%28VS.85%29.aspx). It's standard on all Unixy and network devices, but a little less frequently used on Windows. Check out the [Net-SNMP site](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/) for loads of info. Also, I'd recommend using the free [SNMP-Informant Standard Edition program](http://www.wtcs.org/informant/) to beef up Windows' ability to report via SNMP.

Other features of WMI are covered in other protocols like [Perfmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490957.aspx) for performance statistics, and [ADSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772170%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP) for authentication & authorization.

Comment: I found this blog post for additional info. http://vellon.com/2008/06/23/monitoring-what-you-dont-know-can-hurt-you/

Comment: ADSI has been pretty helpful for me managing IIS in the past when WMI had related data in different WMI classes.

Answer (score 0):

OESIS Framework is comparable to WMI specifically with respect to monitoring:

-- Windows OS patch state, 3rd party security application configuration/patch state.

It differs from WMI in that:

-- additional security application types beyond firewall and AV/AS are monitored, e.g. back-up client, hard disk encryption client, 3rd party patch management clients, etc.
-- non-Windows operating systems such as Linux, Mac and Android are also supported

The framework supports the following programming languages: C++, COM, Java